# Problems with angulars node_mudules

Tags: git, node-modules, angular8

My question is, if node_modules are in .gitignore file, how my team are supose to work, if to build, serve, and generate, we need some of the node_modules.

Comment: Just give your team your package.json file - in other words, commit your package.json file. Then npm will create the correct node_modules for your teammates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should have the following in place:

- package.json containing the used libraries
- package-lock.json containing the exact versions used
- .npmrc containing the local nexus instance

All is geared towards fixating the versions and being reproducible, even if the online version of a library is no longer available.

Please check the locations in the json files when switching to a local nexus proxy, the nexus should be referred.

Please take care that the indirect dependencies may still be loaded directly. It’s hard to figure out when that happens.

Comment: I think you mean `package-lock.json`

Comment: Sure. Corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

The `node_modules` folder contains all of your dependencies and it's correct to exclude it from your repository using `.gitignore`.

A standard setup procedure for anyone on your team working on this project would be:

- Clone the repository
- Run `npm install`

When you run `npm install`, the list of dependencies which are detailed in your `package.json` will be downloaded so the newly cloned repo will have access to the dependencies it needs.